# Gunicorn touch-reload

Tags: gunicorn

Does gunicorn have something like touch-reload of uwsgi?

I'm developing some web application, and need to check some changes. Earlier I've used uwsgi with touch-reload and it is awesome! But I've changed it to gunicorn for some reason (generated 0 bytes) and I can't see any autoreload/autorestart on code changes.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Since gunicorn 19.8, you can specify `--reload-extra-file` to watch files, refer to http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload-extra-files. Do not forget `--reload` or `--reload-extra-file` does not work.

Answer (score -2):

`--touch-reload=path/to/file` for uwsgi == `--reload /path/to/file` for gunicorn

Comment: You can't add a filename to the `--reload` option in gunicorn. It checks whether any of your files are changed.

Comment: For Gunicorn, reload restart workers only when code changes, and it doesn't get  file path as an argument.